# Is there anyway to save HTML form data without a server?

Tags: html, dropbox

I have a website on Dropbox that I like to play around with, but I don't have a personal server.

Is there anyway to save HTML form data without a server?

Comment: Save as in your local machine only? Cookies, LocalStorage, etc.

Comment: I take the term, "save" here to be used loosely.  The only way I can think of is to make an e-mail form and have it email to your address.

Comment: One way could be with Google Docs.

Comment: You can set up a local server environment on your computer with something like XAMPP (for PC) or MAMP (for Mac). That lets you really give code a run for its money. But better still, why not just get a hosting account? You can get them for a few dollars a month.

Comment: I know that you want to do this with no server, but believe me, servers are lots of fun to work with! Try www.ipage.com it is affordable, and easy to use!

Comment: This is actually a very cool question! +1

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways to store form data without a server:

1. save the data in localStorage (or sessionStorage), with JavaScript
2. save it in cookies, with JavaScript
3. use `method=GET` so that the form data is included in the request URL; if you use `action=foo.html`, then JavaScript code at foo.html will be able to read the form data from `document.location`
4. use `action=mailto:...`, which causes form data to be sent by e-mail, provided that the browser is configured to do so. (It might be argued that this is not completely server-free, since the e-mail will pass through an e-mail server.)

All of these ways store the data in a manner that allows access to it in special ways only.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store your form on localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('formData', $('form').serialize());
```

or sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('formData', $('form').serialize());
```

The samples needs [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and would store the serialized data from ALL forms in current document. If your want to save just a single form or a specific field you can change `form` to another valid jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/selector/

You can access the serialized data with `localStorage.getItem('formData')` (localStorage) or `sessionStorage.getItem('formData')` (sessionStorage).

LocalStorage is compatible with the most browsers. See: http://www.html5rocks.com/de/features/storage

[image: Browser compatibility WebStorage]

If you want to be sure you can also use Cookies and JavaScript.
You can use this JS-functions to create/delete cookies:

```
function setCookie(name,value,mins) {
    var expires = "";
    if (mins) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(mins*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is a sample how to do with JavaScript:

```
setCookie('formData', $('form').serialize(), 525600);
```

You can access the serialized data with `getCookie('formData')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a server on your own computer very easily by install XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html. Then you can do all of the testing you like. XAMPP will set up PHP, MySQL and Apache (and some tools) to let you do some testing, and it's self-contained in a single folder.

Comment: This is true, but it should have been posted as a comment, not an answer, since the question explicitly says “without a server”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela the question specifically stated that he doesnt have a personal server, but the asker may not have been aware that he can easily create one for himself. My answer resolves his conundrum in a simple way which avoids trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0):

really!?

Well if its to use or to learn I would suggest [USBWebserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/download.php) (Windows only)

Its plug and play, just download click the .exe and you have a local webserver running with php and mysql.